# Can we make tags have "license" in them?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some tags like the [gpl](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl) and [mit](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit) are awfully short. For someone not knowing much in licensing, they will look ambiguous. Of course, this is clarified in the tag excerpts themselves, but the aesthetic that they provide on posts doesn't clarify that.

***Here's what I propose:***

For any licenses that have a tag associated with them, let's append `-license` to them. For example:

- [gpl](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl) -> [gpl-license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl-license)
- [mit](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit) -> [mit-license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit-license)

An alternative is that we could add tag synonyms for these options, one way round or the other.

What do you think? Rename, synonymize, or do nothing?

Comment: I don't think this is needed or would even help.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt tags like gpl and mit look more ambiguous to newcomers than they are (which verson gpl and which MIT license?). If they do, I doubt that, for example, gpl-license would be more clear to a newcomer than gpl (not to mention that the l already stands for license). I don't see this fixing any problem.

Comment: I agree, that isn't broken, we don't need to fix it.